# Make android swipe end effect

Tags: javascript, css

I try to make this effect using css. 
This is the effect:
[image]

I try to make div that:

```
  div {
    height: 300px; 
    width: 10px; 
    position: absolute; 

    border-radius: 0px 500px 500px 0; 
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 500px 500px 0; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 500px 500px 0; 
    background-color: grey; 
    opacity:0.1;
  }
```

and then by css change the width of this effect.But it look very ugly it more square then circle and also I the change in the width dont make it become like the effect. it looks like the shape become bigger in width but not become more circle...

How can I make this effect by css/js ? everything that I tried with the div look very bad.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effect is a little tricky because of its shape. The key is that the circle that you are creating with the div has to be moved mostly off screen to get a curve that aligns more with the example you gave.

```
.container .effect{
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:80%;
    top:10%;
    right:-140px;
    background-color:#fff;
    border-radius:100% 100% 100% 100%;
    transition:width 500ms ease-in-out, right 500ms ease-in-out, opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
    opacity:.7;
}
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amnszakL/2/) with more details. Try turning the overflow:hidden off on the .container element to see more details of whats going on. The JavaScript is just to show the effect happening.

**Side note: the background image is not my own and was used for education purposes. Credit belongs with the original owner.

Answer (score 0):

Just give it a try (Don't forget to **emulate touch events** in chrome):

```js
var _div = document.getElementById('wrapper');
var _elem = document.getElementById('div');
_div.addEventListener('touchmove', function () {
    _elem.style.width = '60px';
});
_div.addEventListener('touchend', function () {
    _elem.style.width = '0';
});
```

```css
    *, html {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #div {
        height: 95%;
        width: 0;
        top: 2.5%;
        position: absolute;
        border-radius: 0 500px 500px 0;
        -moz-border-radius: 0 500px 500px 0;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0 500px 500px 0;
        background-color: gray;
        opacity: 0.1;
        -webkit-transition: width .2s; /* Safari */
        transition: width .2s;
    }

    #wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: darkgreen;
    }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id='div'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another take using pseudo-elements and transforms. When scroll reaches end on both sides, the *faux-rubber-banding* effect will show up.

Works with mouse scroll to test on non-touch screen desktops. For Chrome, can emulate mouse events to test.

**Demo Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/v4mLkttL/

**Demo Snippet**:

```js
var $wrap = $('#wrap'), startX, isDrag = false;

$wrap.on('touchstart', function(e) {
    startX = e.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX; isDrag = true;
});
$wrap.on('touchmove', function(e) {
    var delta = e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].clientX - startX, 
        pos = $(this).scrollLeft(), w = $(this).width(), 
        iw = $(this).innerWidth(), sh = this.scrollWidth
    ;
    if (isDrag) {
        if ((delta > 0) && (pos <= 0)) {
            $wrap.addClass('rubberLeft');
            isDrag = false; e.preventDefault(); 
        }
        if ((delta < 0) && (pos + iw >= sh)) {
            $wrap.addClass('rubberRight');
            isDrag = false; e.preventDefault(); 
        } 
    }
});
$wrap.on('touchend', function(e) {
    isDrag = false; clearRubber();
});

$wrap.on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
    var start = e.originalEvent, 
        delta = start.wheelDelta || -start.detail, 
        pos = $(this).scrollLeft(), w = $(this).width(), 
        iw = $(this).innerWidth(), sh = this.scrollWidth
    ;
    this.scrollLeft += delta * -1;
    if (pos <= 0) { $wrap.addClass('rubberLeft'); setTimeout(clearRubber, 600); }
    else if (pos + iw >= sh) { $wrap.addClass('rubberRight'); setTimeout(clearRubber, 600); }
    else { clearRubber(); }
    e.preventDefault();    
});

function clearRubber() { $wrap.removeClass('rubberLeft').removeClass('rubberRight'); }
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
html, body { height: 100vh; width: 100vw; overflow: hidden; }
#wrap {
    min-width: 100vw; height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x: scroll;
    background-color: #000; white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
#wrap img { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; }
#wrap::before, #wrap::after {
    content: ''; display: block;
    position: absolute; top: 4%; 
    width: 100px; height: 90%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-radius: 50%; transform: translateX(0px);
    transition: transform 0.5s;    
}
#wrap::before { left: -105px; }
#wrap::after { right: -105px; }
#wrap.rubberLeft::before { transform: translateX(45px); }
#wrap.rubberRight::after { transform: translateX(-45px); }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">
    <img class="page" src='//lorempixel.com/240/320' />
    <img class="page" src='//lorempixel.com/241/320' />
    <img class="page" src='//lorempixel.com/239/320' />
    <img class="page" src='//lorempixel.com/240/320' />
    <img class="page" src='//lorempixel.com/241/320' />
    <img class="page" src='//lorempixel.com/239/320' />
</div>
```